# TensorFlow slice Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to do something like this:

```
def f(ind, region, matrix):

    ...
```

Parameter ind is placeholder or Tensor and contains coordinate x, y of central element, region is tuple of integers that represents shape of region. And you need to calculate indices and get region from matrix.

Example:

```
ind = [2, 2]
region = [3, 3]
matrix = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
          [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
          [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 
          [4, 4, 4, 4, 4], 
          [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]

indices = tf.placeholder(tf.in32, shape=...)
region = [3, 3]
mat = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=...)

res = f(indices, region, mat)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    r = sess.run(res, feed_dict={ indices: ind, mat: matrix })
```

Result is:

```
   r = [[2, 2, 2], 
        [3, 3, 3], 
        [4, 4, 4]]
```

because central element on (2, 2) is 3, and region of size 3 by 3 around is given by result r.

Comment: What is wrong with https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice

Comment: As Dinesh pointed out, you just need to do some arithmetic to go from your center based coordinates to `tf.slice` edge based coordinates and call `tf.slice`.